# symfony2 doctrine caching query with time inside

Tags: caching, symfony, doctrine

Hi i want to cache the result of query. I have already:

```
    $now = time();
    $lastMonth = 30*24*3600;

    $period = $now-$lastMonth;

    $qb=$this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('s') 
             ->addSelect('u') 
             ->addSelect('COUNT(s.id) AS suggestedCount')
             ->from('WallBundle:Status', 's') 
             ->innerJoin('s.user', 'u') 
             ->where('s.time >= :period')
             ->andWhere('s.suggested_status = true')
             ->groupBy('s.user')
             ->setParameter('period', $period)
             ->orderBy('suggestedCount', 'DESC')
             ->setMaxResults(10)
             ; 

    $query=$qb->getQuery();  
    $query->useResultCache(true,30800,'elite10');
    $query->useQueryCache(true);

    return $query->getResult();
```

But it still does not cache. When i remove the

```
"->where('s.time >= :period')"
```

and

```
->setParameter('period', $period)
```

It works... so.. where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Query cache (`$query->useQueryCache(true);`), but also you are constructing a query that uses a parameter that changes every milisecond (`$period = $now-$lastMonth;`). Therefore no two queries are the same and couldn't be cached. If your needs alow it, round the parameter to x hours.